# How do I serve Multiple sitemap.xml in Nginx

Tags: nginx, redirect, sitemap

I'm scenario I'm using Nginx/1.20.0, I have my `robots.txt` want to `https://new-dev.example.com/sitemap/sitemap-index.xml`, but it's just throwing a 404,

I tried this:

```
location /robots.txt {
    alias /Directory-containing-robots-file/robots.txt;
}
```

and

```
location ~ ^/sitemap/(.*) {
    rewrite ^/sitemap/([^/]*)$ /var/www/sitemap/$1 redirect;
}
```

is correct but we want to serve the file, not redirect it

```
try_files /var/www/sitemap/$1 $uri;
```

is close but getting a 500 when loading paths

I'm not sure I follow how we'd configure that still for all files We have `/var/www/sitemap/` where all our XML files will be located then `https://new-dev.example.com/sitemap/sitemap-index.xml` needs to load `sitemap-index.xml` from that path

similarly `https://new-dev.example.com/sitemap/articles/63300.xml` should serve `/var/www/sitemap/articles/63300.xml`

Answer (score 0):

From the [nginx documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) you should be able to use just:

```
location /sitemap/ {
    alias /var/www/sitemap/;
}
```

Then everything in the `sitemap/` path of your website will be served from the `/var/www/sitemap/` directory.